# Python3 typehints - After passing in a Tuple of Types, specify that the return value is a Tuple of instances of those Types

Tags: python, generics, sqlalchemy, type-hinting, mypy

I currently use a few complicated typehints for "shortcut" functions I have made for dB calls with `sqlalchemy`.  For example, instead of having to write,

```
users: List[User] = User.query.all()
```

I created a shortcut function in my base model,

```
@classmethod
def qall(cls: Type[T_DBModel]) -> List[T_DBModel]:
    cls.query.all()
```

so now I can just write `users = User.qall()` and the typehint works like a charm for my IDE (PyCharm) - it correctly recognises that this will be `List[User]` without me having to specify.

Now though, I want to do the same for `sqlalchemy`'s `with_entities` function.  With that, you can specify you want the dB call to return a tuple of things, i.e.,

```
users_roles: List[Tuple[User, Role]] = User.query.with_entities(User, Role).all()
```

And I want to write a similar shortcut method as above for this,

```
@classmethod
def qwith_entities(cls: Type[T_DBModel], retvals: T) -> List[T]:
    cls.query.with_entities(*retvals).all()
```

So I can "shortcut" use it in the same way,

```
users_roles = User.qwith_entities((User, Role))
```

Problem is, with that signature, instead of the typehint specifies getting back `List[Tuple[User, Role]]`, it's `List[Tuple[Type[User], Type[Role]]]` which isn't correct, and isn't the return value.

If I break this up, into multiple functions it's all good there,

```
@classmethod
def qwith_entity(cls: Type[T_DBModel], retval: Type[T]) -> List[T]:
    cls.query.with_entities(retval).all()
```

It knows `Base.qwith_entity(User)` will be `List[User]` (you would never do this, just an example) and

```
@classmethod
def qwith_2_entities(cls: Type[T_DBModel], retval_1: Type[T], retval_2: Type[Y]) -> List[Tuple[T, Y]]:
    cls.query.with_entities(retval_1, retval_2).all()
```

or

```
@classmethod
def qwith_2_entities(cls: Type[T_DBModel], retvals: Tuple[Type[T], Type[Y]]) -> List[Tuple[T, Y]]:
    cls.query.with_entities(*retvals).all()
```

Which would know `users_roles = Base.qwith_2_entities((User, Role))` will be `List[Tuple[User, Role]]`

But I don't know how to, nor if it's possible to properly typehint a *variable* length `Tuple` of different `Type`s, and the return value should unpack that, i.e. something stupid like,

```
@classmethod
def qwith_entities(cls: Type[T_DBModel], retvals: Tuple[Type[...T]]) -> List[Tuple[T]]:
    cls.query.with_entities(*retvals).all()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need [variadic generics](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/193) for you to accurately spell out the signature; *this is not yet possible but it'd perhaps would look like*:

```
Ts = TypeVar('Ts', variadic=True)

@classmethod
def qwith_2_entities(cls: Type[T_DBModel], retvals: Tuple[Type[Ts], ...]) -> List[Tuple[Ts, ...]]:
    cls.query.with_entities(*retvals).all()
```

where the `Ts` `TypeVar` is variadic, and `Tuple[Type[Ts], ...]` is expanded to mean `Tuple[Type[T_0], Type[T_1], Type[T_2], ...])` and the type in the returned list is expanded to mean `Tuple[T_0, T_1, T_2, ...])`

However, as mentioned, that's not yet a syntax that's available. The work-around is to use `@overload`s with 1, 2, 3, etc distinct `TypeVar`s, at least enough for all your usecases:

```
T1 = TypeVar('T1')
T2 = TypeVar('T2')
T3 = TypeVar('T3')
T4 = TypeVar('T4')
# add more as needed

@overload
def qwith_2_entities(cls: Type[T_DBModel], retvals: Tuple[Type[T1]]) -> List[Tuple[T1]]:
    pass
@overload
def qwith_2_entities(cls: Type[T_DBModel], retvals: Tuple[Type[T1], Type[T2]]) -> List[Tuple[T1, T2]]:
    pass
@overload
def qwith_2_entities(cls: Type[T_DBModel], retvals: Tuple[Type[T1], Type[T2], Type[T3]]) -> List[Tuple[T1, T2, T3]]:
    pass
@overload
def qwith_2_entities(cls: Type[T_DBModel], retvals: Tuple[Type[T1], Type[T2], Type[T3], Type[T4]]) -> List[Tuple[T1, T2, T3, T4]]:
    pass
# add more overloads as needed
@classmethod
def qwith_2_entities(cls, retvals):
    cls.query.with_entities(*retvals).all()
```